# Как через AsyncTaskLoader вызвать метод для изменения UI

Tags: java, android, activity, android-loader

У меня есть активность и `AsyncTaskLoader`.

Активность:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String>,
        LoadUsersInFileLoader.LoaderProgessListener, View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView tvProcessed;
    private String processedSubscribers;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvProcessed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textProcessed);
        processedSubscribers = getString(R.string.processed);

        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void setSubscriberProcessed(int processedSubscribers) {
        tvProcessed.setText(processedSubscribers + " " + processedSubscribers);
    }

    ...
}
```

`Loader`:

```
public class LoadUsersInFileLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<String> {
    interface LoaderProgessListener {
        void setSubscriberProcessed(int processedSubscribers);

        ...
    }

    private int checkedSubscriber = 0;

    ...

    public LoadUsersInFileLoader(Context context, Bundle bundle) {
        super(context);

        ...

        progressListener = (LoaderProgessListener) context;
    }

    @Override
    public String loadInBackground() {
        ...

        removeUnwanted();

        ...

        return returnedString;
    }

    //Отсеивает ненужных подписчиков
    private void removeUnwanted() {
            ...

            checkedSubscriber++;
            progressListener.setSubscriberProcessed(checkedSubscriber);

            ...
         }
}
```

P.S. Весь код, который ненужен в данной ситуации я убрал, так как его много.

---

`Проблема`: при вызове метода слушателя `setSubscriberProcessed` выскакивает ошибка. На сколько я понял, программа возмущается из-за того, что я пытаюсь вызвать изменение *UI* из другого потока.

Ошибка:

```
04-03 01:14:42.819 11265-11418/com.dugin_rostislav.findneedusers E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1
Process: com.dugin_rostislav.findneedusers, PID: 11265
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:142)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7109)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1032)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17830)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17830)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17830)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17830)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17830)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17830)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17830)
    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:7167)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4106)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3950)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3925)
    at com.dugin_rostislav.findneedusers.MainActivity.setSubscriberProcessed(MainActivity.java:74)
    at com.dugin_rostislav.findneedusers.LoadUsersInFileLoader.removeUnwanted(LoadUsersInFileLoader.java:92)
    at com.dugin_rostislav.findneedusers.LoadUsersInFileLoader.loadInBackground(LoadUsersInFileLoader.java:80)
    at com.dugin_rostislav.findneedusers.LoadUsersInFileLoader.loadInBackground(LoadUsersInFileLoader.java:20)
    at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:296)
    at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:54)
    at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:42)
    at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:128)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**Вопрос**: как обратиться к методу активности, чтобы изменить `TextView` из `loadInBackground`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё верно - вы обращаетесь к UI из не UI потока.
Решение простое - меняйте UI из основного потока так:

```
@Override
public void setSubscriberProcessed(int processedSubscribers) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
             //выполнится в UI потоке
             tvProcessed.setText(processedSubscribers + " " + processedSubscribers);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Хм... А что это за такой хороший метод?)

Comment: @bukashka101, он как раз для этих случаев) И название говорящее)

Comment: @bukashka101, и я таки нашёл способ нормального форматирования вывода ошибки в логах - б блокнот пихнул и сделал замену этих аццких отступов на 4 пробела)

Comment: Ура-ура: `legendCounter++`)

Comment: Отступы? Блокнот? Вы недооцениваете мою лень :D. С `UI` заработало красиво... Эти быстро меняющиеся циферки выглядят прекрасно!) Правда тут баг... Я даю группу на сортировку подписчиков, в группе всего 2046. Программа мне пишет, что отсортировала 3000... :))

Comment: @bukashka101, лень - двигатель прогресса) А 3000, как мне мой магический шар подсказывает, у вас из-за того, что вы цикл на 2046 юзере не останавливаете `break`-ом, а продолжаете... Вот и 3000)

Comment: Хах... Уже 6000). Я телефону экран выключил... Но, блин, все же циклы останавливаются!

Comment: @bukashka101, ну, запилите ещё вопрос - посмотрим)

Comment: Да я только что залил. Но с этим попробую сам разобраться. У меня подозрение, что мне вк лишние ответы кидает.

Comment: Я понял в чем ошибка. Я постоянно запрашиваю первые 1000 подписчиков, а нужно, после получения, делать отступ на 1000. Но и вк, видимо, не без греха. Два раза подряд мне ответ кидает иногда.

Comment: @bukashka101, facebook хуже - я на днях его впиливал, так оно там всё гораздо сложнее, чем вконтакт(

Comment: Как хорошо, что у меня нет фейсбука..)

Comment: @bukashka101, ага) Там так пришлось с бубном поплясать чтоб id-шник юзера получить... Аж ппц(

Comment: Сейчас маленький фиксик сделаю и пойду спать. А завтра уже сделаю запись в файл и задокументирую до конца код (хотя я так наговнокодил, ввиду того, что алгоритм нестандартный и все в `Loader'e` делал).

Comment: @bukashka101, сон и документация кода - хорошие, годные вещи) Пойду и я. Спокойной ночи)

Comment: Спокойной! :)).